# django-paypal signal update

Tags: django, django-paypal

I've been picking my way though django-paypal documentation and have got a signal connecting when I send a IPN from the sandbox simulator.

I can do:

```
UserProfile.objects.update(has_paid=True)
```

I can also do:

```
UserProfile.objects.update(middle_name=sender.custom) # sender.custom set to "Lyndon" on IPN
```

and everyone gets a year free. Not what I want...
What I'd like to do is

```
up = UserProfile.objects.get(user=ipn_obj.custom)
up.has_paid = False
up.save()
```

but on such occasions I get a server error (500) message on the Instant Payment Notification (IPN)
 simulator.

```
IPN delivery failed. HTTP error code 500: Internal Server Error
```

I still get a Paypal IPN in my database and it will show up not flagged and with a payment status of "Completed". However, the signal is not connecting.

I'm just not getting something (or multiple things!) here. Any pointers much appreciated.

T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if I paid attention...

```
up = UserProfile.objects.get(user.username=ipn_obj.custom)
```

user.**username**...

Comment: can you explain more in detail the *****username***** part please

Comment: @SuburbanFilth the ** were added by the site. I was trying to format the username in bold to make it more obvious. The formatting didn't work perhaps because it's a block of code.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use that,

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user=ipn_obj.custom).update(has_paid=False)
```

For that kind of bugs, which you can not understand what is the problem use ipdb:

you should install ipdb,

```
$ pip install ipdb
```

and to run go to your code which doesn't work and add,

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

when you run on your local (I mean with runserver) and make request to make that code pieces run, you will see the trace after the above line.

Note that to go next use "n" and to continue use "c" on ipdb.